# curl wont work on wamp can open the WordPress installer but when click go come up with this : curl_init() in C:\wamp\www\installer.php on line 364

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, localhost

Its a nightmare, whenever I click go on the installer page I come up with

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\wamp\www\installer.php on line 364
```

I have no idea what to do, have edited both Apache and PHP to remove the curl code, still not working.

Comment: Enable the curl extension in php.ini.

Answer (score 2):

Enable the php extension and then restart wampserver

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, download the curl fix extensions from here ->

http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/

try this link first -> php_curl-5.3.13-VC9-x64.zip

It seems to be a Windows 7 64 bit issue.  Don't forget to restart all services after the change.